# Creation of resource cert-manager/letsencrypt failed because the Kubernetes API server reported that the apiVersion for this resource does not exist

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, cert-manager, pulumi

I am having issues installing the `cert-manager` Helm chart **and** setting up a LetsEncrypt cluster issuer using Pulumi in our Azure Kubernetes cluster.  We are using Kubernetes version  1.21.2 and cert-manager. 1.5.3.

When running `pulumi up` before any of the resources exist I get the following error:

```
kubernetes:cert-manager.io/v1:ClusterIssuer (cert-manager-letsencrypt):
    error: creation of resource cert-manager/letsencrypt failed because the Kubernetes API server reported that the apiVersion for this resource does not exist. Verify that any required CRDs have been created: no matches for kind "ClusterIssuer" in version "cert-manager.io/v1"
    error: update failedaToolsCertManager                 cert-manager
```

I can confirm that the cluster issuer hasn't been created by running `kubectl get clusterissuer`.

When running `pulumi up` again **it succeeds and the letsencrypt ClusterIssuer is correctly created**.

I don't want to have to run `pulumi up` consecutive times to reach a successful deployment.  Can anyone see what the issue is here?

**C# stack definition:**

```
// Create new namespace
var certManagerNamespace = new Namespace("cert-manager", 
    new NamespaceArgs()
    {
        Metadata = new ObjectMetaArgs
        {
            Name = "cert-manager"
        }
    },
    options);

// Install cert-manager using Helm
var certManagerChart = new Chart("cert-manager", 
    new ChartArgs
    {
        Chart = "cert-manager",
        Version = "1.5.3",
        Namespace = certManagerNamespace.Metadata.Apply(m => m.Name),
        Values =
        {
            ["installCRDs"] = "true"
        },
        FetchOptions = new ChartFetchArgs
        {
            Repo = "https://charts.jetstack.io"
        }
    },
    options);

// Create ClusterIssuer using LetsEncrypt
var clusterIssuer = new ClusterIssuer($"{name}-letsencrypt",
    new ClusterIssuerArgs()
    {
        ApiVersion = "cert-manager.io/v1",
        Kind = "ClusterIssuer",
        Metadata = new ObjectMetaArgs()
        {
            Name = "letsencrypt",
            Namespace = "cert-manager",
        },
        Spec = new ClusterIssuerSpecArgs()
        {
            Acme = new ClusterIssuerSpecAcmeArgs()
            {
                Email = "administrator@blahblah.com",
                Server = "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory",
                PrivateKeySecretRef = new ClusterIssuerSpecAcmePrivateKeySecretRefArgs()
                {
                    Name = "letsencrypt"
                },
                Solvers =
                {
                        new ClusterIssuerSpecAcmeSolversArgs()
                        {
                            Http01 = new ClusterIssuerSpecAcmeSolversHttp01Args()
                            {
                                Ingress = new ClusterIssuerSpecAcmeSolversHttp01IngressArgs()
                                {
                                    Class = "nginx"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    },
    new CustomResourceOptions()
    {
        DependsOn = certManagerChart,
        Provider = options.Provider
    });
```

The cluster issuer definition from Pulumi:

```
+ kubernetes:cert-manager.io/v1:ClusterIssuer: (create)
    [urn=urn:pulumi:preprod::MyAks::kubernetes:cert-manager.io/v1:ClusterIssuer::cert-manager-letsencrypt]
    [provider=urn:pulumi:preprod::MyAks::k8sx:service:MyAks$pulumi:providers:kubernetes::k8s-provider::5191350f-c03b-4796-bc48-053584e2c996]
    apiVersion: "cert-manager.io/v1"
    kind      : "ClusterIssuer"
    metadata  : {
        labels   : {
            app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: "pulumi"
        }
        name     : "letsencrypt"
        namespace: "cert-manager"
    }
    spec      : {
        acme: {
            email              : "administrator@blahblah.com"
            privateKeySecretRef: {
                name: "letsencrypt"
            }
            server             : "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
            solvers            : [
                [0]: {
                    http01: {
                        ingress: {
                            class: "nginx"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```